# Java way to Azure CLI and KubeCTL

Tags: java, azure, kubernetes

I have a very basic `REST API` that provides some information, which was written with `JAX-RS`.

Now I want to implement some azure cli commands, like [az acr repository list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr/repository?view=azure-cli-latest) as well as kubectl.

I found the [Azure Java SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java), and read its [API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.management.containerregistry?view=azure-java-stable), but I couldn't figure out how I will basically list the repositories.

[Kubernetes](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/aks-java-manage-kubernetes-cluster) example is much better, but I am stuck with Azure Container Registry.

Basically I am asking a code sample (reference), or tutorial, or guidance.

Comment: I would think this is because repository list is not an Azure level api, but docker repo API. So you need to use docker library to talk to that. I'm quite sure about that. [Here's](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/ae9a299bc15b0516e48eb9f34795d6c3edba220c/src/azure-cli/azure/cli/command_modules/acr/_docker_utils.py#L367) the code behind `az acr repository`.

Comment: Maybe you can try to use the [Docker Registry API](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/) in Java to get the repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever my experience of using Azure docs, it's little hard to find API doc which will work for you and you may found some discrepancies between docs like one of API via cli vs sdk behaves different.

As per my work with various clouds, most of the cloud clients are inclined to use python SDKs. 3-4 ago, I had used java for openstack, now python. For VCloud, used java but now moving to python, in fact they stopped to provide java sdk.

Hope you have got some pointers.